# Secondary IDs in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am aware that `_id` is already unique. However, due to circumstances, I cannot use it. Each user uses an e-mail address and a username, but I cannot use those either. What I want to use this secondary ID for are friend codes. I do not require them to be short. If they are as long and random as `_id`, that will not be a problem since users will not have to enter them anywhere. Can such property be assigned during the execution of the `insertOne()` function?

Answer (score 0):

You cant set `unique index` for those fields
`db.users.createIndex( { email: 1, username: 1}, { unique: true } )`

---

Referrer  [Unique Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/)

Comment: I know, but there are other reasons I cannot use them.

Comment: Could you tell me what your reasons? Maybe i found another way

Comment: I do not want them to not be public to other users, pretty much.

Comment: I think you can create an md5 string base on username and email, and this field is unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a model to generate the `_id` or not, but for as far as I'm aware there is no option to allow the generation of a second unique identifier automatically.

You could tweak the `insertOne` method by using `uuid` as such:

```js
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

function insertOne(collectionName, document, writeConcern) {
   const [document, ...otherArgs] = args;
   db[collectionName].insertOne({ id: new uuidv4(), ...document }, writeConcern)
}

try {
   insertOne( 'collectionName', { item: "card", qty: 15 } );
} catch (e) {
   print (e);
};
```

Additionally, if you prefer calling `db.collection.insertOne` every time and have the id added automatically, you should be able to do so by using it as such (haven't tested it, but it should work):

```js
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

db.collection.prototype.insertOne = function(document, writeConcern) {
   db.collection.insertOne({ id: new uuidv4(), ...document }, writeConcern)
};

try {
   db.collection.insertOne( { item: "card", qty: 15 } );
} catch (e) {
   print (e);
};
```